# proper OOP and flexibility between classes in java

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm new to java, I would like some advice from you:

- I would insert in **setPreferredSize()** the width and the height of the **manager  class**, without using the "evil" statics, can someone tell me the smartest thing to do in this case?
- is it possible  **to not  create** a constructor in  manager class and pass the width and height always respecting the OOP's flexibility classes?
- I was wrong to write **add(Panel.getPanel())**, it is correct? 
  it respects the OOP?

Tell me where am I wrong in this code or what to fix, I want to learn,thanks you.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          final MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
          mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

   public MainFrame() {
    initFrame();
    }

   private void initFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(Panel.getPanel());
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   }
 }


public class Panel extends JPanel  {

    public Panel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(/*?????????*/));
    }                   
}



 public class Manager  {
      private int width = 700;
      private int height = 700;
          // Some unrelated code follows


      public int getHeight(){
          return height;
       }
       public int getWidth(){
          return width;
       }

 }
```

Comment: 1) [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). 
2) Is there a reason your extending  `JPanel` or `JFrame` you are not adding functionality, 
3) In java methods name starts with lower-case following a camel-case style by convention. 4) Your variables in Manager could be `final`

Comment: @nachokk please tell me what method doesn't follow the java convention? all methods in my program follows camel-case convenction , for example: getHeight(),anyway, in the panel i added a keylistener and mouselistener, the frame has the functionality to start the application as you can see it has a main method.

Comment: This questions may be better fit at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would insert in setPreferredSize() the width and the height of the
>   manager class, without using the "evil" statics, can someone tell me
>   the smartest thing to do in this case?

Read this, should help [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) . In general let the layout-manager to lead with this.

> is it possible to not create a constructor in manager class and pass
>   the width and height always respecting the OOP's flexibility classes?

Yep, make them class variable(**static**) and also `final`,  this means

Option 1

```
 //check class name
 public class Manager  {
      public static final int width = 700;
      public static final int height = 700;
 }
```

Option 2,

```
 public class Manager  {
      private static int width = 700; //could be final
      private static int height = 700; // could be final
          // Some unrelated code follows


      public static int getHeight(){
         //you can make some algorithm in this way
          return height;
       }
       public static int getWidth(){
         //you can make some algorithm in this way
          return width;
       }

 }
```

Option 3: Define an Enum

```
public class Manager {

 public enum Dimension{
    WIDTH(700),
    HEIGHT(700);
   private final Integer value;

   Dimension(Integer value){
      this.value=value;
   }

   public Integer getValue(){
       return value;
   }
 }

}
```

> I was wrong to write add(Panel.getPanel()), it is correct? it respects
>   the OOP?

No, it isn't correct unless `getPanel()` is a **static**  method. You should create an instance of your `JPanel`

```
 JPanel panel = new Panel();
 add(panel);
```

Also you are using inheritance in a bad way. You are subclassing but you are not adding any new functionality, and if you decide to subclass don't use `Panel` cause it's the name is like `java.awt.Panel` and it's very confusing.

Read more in [oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: i' m so happy, i ' ve response in a very linear way :D

Comment: i don' t paste all my code, my interest was in this thing,that you explained well, i added listeners to the panel.